# How to blind data in data warehouse when sending from preanonymized layer to anonymized layer while keeping referential integrity of all key columns

Tags: data-warehouse, data-masking

Have to blind PII data before loading the data to anonymized layer such that it can't be traced back but also need to maintain the referential integrity between all the tables across all key columns. What is the most suitable way to blind data in this scenario.

Have looked at different blinding techniques but not able to find the one which would keep the referential integrity after blinding the key columns

Comment: Meta-question: Do you say "to bind data" in this context? I would have said "hide", but I'm not a native speaker.

Comment: Yes i meant blind data, mask the data or anonymize the data

Comment: Why not use a deterministic hash function?